# Is there a way to output the numbers, that are in string format, only from a python list?

Tags: python, list, extract

Simple question:

How to only extract integers (no floats) from a list of strings?

Like this:

```
list_1 = [['50', 'ALA', 'A', '53', '5', '4'], ['55', 'GLY', 'A', '60', '1', '6'], ['67', 'ILE', 'A', '71', '5', '5']]
```

To this:

```
list_1 = [['50', '53', '5', '4'], ['55', '60', '1', '6'], ['67', '71', '5', '5']]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, all numbers in the list are integers.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `str.isdigit` method.

```
>>> list_1 = ['50', 'ALA', 'A', '53', '5', 'N', '4']
>>> list_1 = [x for x in list_1 if x.isdigit()]
>>> list_1
['50', '53', '5', '4']
```

Note that this will not work for floating point representations of numbers.

```
>>> '650.43'.isdigit()
False
```

If you want to filter these as well, write a traditional loop.

```
>>> list_1 = ['50', '650.43', 'test']
>>> result = []
>>> for x in list_1:
...     try:
...         float(x)
...         result.append(x)
...     except ValueError:
...         pass
... 
>>> result
['50', '650.43']
```

Comment: @Stennis If an answer solves your problem, please consider [accepting the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Can I perfom the same coding in a list within a list?

Comment: Like: `[['50', 'ALA', 'A', '53', '5', '4'], ['55', 'GLY', 'A', '60', '1', '6'], ['67', 'ILE', 'A', '71', '5', '5']]`

Comment: Found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by this piece of code, it will manage floats too, handling errors and exceptions.

> Loop can be converted into comprehension for more Pythonic way.

```
def isfloat(value):
  try:
    float(value)
    return True
  except:
    return False

v = ['50', 'ALA', 'A', '53', '5', 'N', '4']
result = []
for x, i in enumerate(map(isfloat, v)):
    if i is True:
    result.append(v[x])

print result # [50, 53, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list_1 = ['50', 'ALA', 'A', '53', '5', 'N', '4']

digits = []
for item in list_1:
    for subitem in item.split():
        if(subitem.isdigit()):
            digits.append(subitem)
print(digits)
```

Output:

```
['50', '53', '5', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can do this

```
list_1 = ['50', 'ALA', 'A', '53', '5', 'N', '4']
list_2 =[]
for i in range(len(list_1)):
    if list_1[i].isnumeric():
        list_2.append(list_1[i])
print(list_2)
```